# jcifs copyTo from one network to other network path not working

Tags: java, file, copy-paste, jcifs

I'm using the [Java CIFS Client Library](https://jcifs.samba.org/) but facing the problem and problem is copyTo function is not working.
I have one folder which contains files. I want to read these files to other network path.

```
 String path1 = "//MACHINE-NAME/SHARE-FOLDER"
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new
     NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN;USERNAME:PASSWORD) 
 SmbFile readFolder = new SmbFile("smb://MACHINE-NAME/SHARE-FOLDER/",auth)
```

This is working fine.
Then i have another network path and define like this and ShareFolder2 is have the read/write access to 'everyone' user.

```
String path2 = "//MACHINE-NAME/SHARE-FOLDER2"
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new
         NtlmPasswordAuthentication(DOMAIN;USERNAME:PASSWORD) 
SmbFile destinationFolder = new SmbFile("smb://MACHINE-NAME/SHARE-FOLDER2/",auth)






ArrayList<SmbFile>  readFiles = readFolder?.listFiles()
    for(file in readFiles ){
       file.copyTo(destinationFolder)

        }
```

Comment: I need answer to this as well, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to copy a file from one shared location to another shared location. You can this like this

```
ArrayList<SmbFile>  readFiles = readFolder?.listFiles()
    for(file in readFiles ){
String name = file.properties.getKey("name")
destinationFolder = new SmbFile(foldersInfo?.destinationFolder+"/"+name,auth)
                    destinationFolder.createNewFile()
                    file.copyTo(destinationFolder)

        }
```

The file which you want to copy that file must be in the destination folder. 
First we will create a file with same name in the destination folder then copy to that folder

Comment: much helpful. Thanks